# Clear duplicates in Oracle table based on two (or more) columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have made a table containing with data that i depict to a dashboard.

Well, there should exist for each month only one record.

My query brings the below Oracle table:

```
select * from PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT order by 2 desc
```

This outputs:

[image]

For example, i want to remove PPL_IMPORT_CALLHOSTED_ESTIMATES double record and keep only one. And so on for other duplicate records. How can a generic query be executed to remove duplications and keep only one row as original?

How would that be possible?

Comment: There not duplicates, they have different start and end times, explain what logic you want to implement to reduce the name field to 1, e.g. max time, min time etc

Comment: its irrelevant the exactly details in time (seconds) I just want to keep *one* of them :) could you please provide a helpful reply?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221866/oracle-delete-duplicates-records/46232665#46232665

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the broadest parameters, minimum start time and maximum end time then use a combination of `MIN`, `MAX` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT PPLP_NAME, MIN(START_TIME) AS START_TIME, MAX(END_TIME) AS END_TIME, ROWS_LOADED
FROM PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT 
GROUP BY PPLP_NAME, ROWS_LOADED
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment *'its irrelevant the exactly details in time (seconds) I just want to keep one of them'*

You can proceed like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PPLP_NAME, TO_CHAR(START_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), TO_CHAR(END_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), ROWS_LOADED
FROM PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT
```